# List with Filepaths search for specific files python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have made a list containing all xlsx files in a directory + subfolders. Now I have a **Pandas Dataframe** with only 1 column and in each row the full path to the xlsx file. I have another **List** containing only the names of the xlsx files **without** full path. I know there is a way of filtering values like df[df[bla == bla]], but I do not know how to do this with a substring of a string.

Anyone has an idea how to get back a List containing **only** the **full paths** of the wanted xlsx files?

This is the dataframe with the full paths
[image]

and this is the filenames list I have

[image]

Comment: I can't understand your data by looking at your explanation. I want to see your data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sorry I will add an image!

Comment: No, data as text _only_ edited into your question please.

Comment: now basically you can see the full paths which lead to for Example DE_CC_261017_Eloqua_Einladung... starting from the O:\ Drive. but the problem is there are more files listed than I actually need 1000 possible files while I only need 100 specific of them

Answer (score 0):

You can search a Pandas DataFrame in like this:

**Searching for a string containing a pattern**

```
    pattern = r'[0-9][a-z]'

    pd.Series(['1', '2', '3a', '3b', '03c']).str.contains(pattern)
```

**Searching for a string matching a patter**

```
    pd.Series(['1', '2', '3a', '3b', '03c']).str.match(pattern)
```

You can find more detailed explanation here. Hope that helps.

Comment: The problem is, I don't want a RegEx, I have the exact name of the file in a list (about 400 file names) and I have the DataFrame with the full file path of all folders including subfolders in another DataFrame. Now I basically want only those full paths which end in one of the file names from the first DataFrame.